# Repeat image border vertically

Tags: html, css

I have looked online for a way to use an image as a border and repeat it vertically so that when the min size of a page has exceeded it will still completely fill in the border on the left and right sides but I cannot seem to find style code that works.  I have got the border to display horizontally but I can use set sizes for horizontal orientation.

Is this possible?  Or does anyone have a better way of accomplishing this type of effect?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `background-repeat: repeat-y;` in your CSS. A working [demo can be seen here.](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/9GLC8/)

HTML

```
<div id="myBG">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#myBG {
    height: 1000px;
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I got thrown off by it being called background-image in examples I had seen.

Comment: Glad that was the answer to your question it's rather simple. Background images behave a little differently, you can't right click and view image the way you would img src="myImage.jpg". Another thing you may want to play around is the CSS3 RGB colors and opacity for your background. Try something like background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.3);

Comment: Yeah I will have to play around with stuff to get it all to work but your answer accomplished my goal.  Hadn't thought to use the background-image for it but I think I was just hoping for a more simple solution.